# ggplot: Scaling geom_text to geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am utilizing unicode characters to create unique shapes within a heatmap (as pictured) using ggplot using the below code. However, I don't know of any way of pulling the size of a ggplot object's geom_tile to scale the unique shapes. Does anyone know of any way to pull this information?

```
library(ggplot2)
cars$category <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"),10)
cars$category2 <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),5)
graph <- ggplot(cars,aes(x=category,y=category2)) + geom_tile() + geom_text(color=cars$speed,label="\u25D6",family = "Arial")
ggsave("test.png",plot=graph,device="png",width=3360,height=3360,units="px",dpi=600)
```

[image: Heatmap]

I've looked around inside the "graph" object, but find no simple way to pull this information, and most answers seem to specify fine tuning the size rather than mathematically computing one.

Comment: The image is not the same as the “graph” object. You should show what efforts you have applied to the language object. Since you have not provided a [MCVE] there’s not a lot more to be said until you do so. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61038443/how-to-remove-state-abbreviations-from-a-choroplethr-map

Comment: @IRTFM My apologies. I've edited my code and the image to make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: The problem is that the size of the tiles varies according to your plotting device, whereas the text is of a fixed size. This means you would have to recalculate the text size every time a plot is drawn or resized. This _can_ be done dynamically, but that would mean creating a new grob type with its own makeContent method - possibly more work than you had in mind. Another option is to use polygons instead of glyphs, since these will always resize proportionately. That would be the best option if you only want one or two different shapes (like half-circles)

Comment: Ah geom_polygon is an alternative I had not thought of. Just curious, is it possible to more easily calculate a new text size if the plotting device itself is fixed? For example, if I only used the ggsave parameters above, would this be easier to calculate?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ggfittext::geom_fit_text()` to resize text dynamically. You'd have to precompute the bounding box for it though (the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax values). We're using the `after_stat()` function here to take the discrete values after mapping them to numeric positions, at which point the distance from one discrete position to the next equals 1.

```r
library(ggplot2)
cars$category <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"),10)
cars$category2 <- rep(c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"),5)

ggplot(cars,aes(x=category,y=category2)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  ggfittext::geom_fit_text(
    aes(
      xmin = after_stat(x - 0.5), xmax = after_stat(x + 0.5),
      ymin = after_stat(y - 0.5), ymax = after_stat(y + 0.5)
    ),
    color = cars$speed, label = "\u25D6", family = "Arial",
    grow = TRUE
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-02-05 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>